# Cannot cast array of Object to array of another interface

Tags: java, generics, casting

I cannot figure out why I keep getting a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object; cannot be cast to ProfileInterface` error

Here is all of the relevant code that keeps giving me the error

Client

```
public static void show() {
    ProfileInterface person = pick();
    if (person == null){
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(p.getName());
    System.out.println("About: " + p.getAbout());
    System.out.println("Following:");

    //error happens at this line below
    ProfileInterface[] following = p.following(4);

    for (ProfileInterface p2 : following) {
        System.out.println(p2.getName());
    }
}
```

Profile class that contains `following` method and extends ProfileInterface

```
private Set<ProfileInterface> friends = new Set<ProfileInterface>();

public ProfileInterface[] following(int count){
    if(count >= friends.getCurrentSize()){

        //And points to this line as the Object Cast Error
        return (ProfileInterface[])friends.toArray();

    }else{
        return (ProfileInterface[])Arrays.copyOf(friends.toArray(), howMany);
    }
}
```

And the Set Class that contains the `toArray` Method

```
@Override
public T[] toArray() {
    T[] returnArray = (T[])new Object[size];
    System.out.println("Size of current array is " +size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size;i++){
        returnArray[i] = setArray[i];
    }

    return returnArray;
}
```

I am casting the return array to a `ProfileInterface[]` but it keeps giving me the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have the following options:

1. Leave the implementation of `Set` as it is, implement your `following()` method without invoking `toArray()`, and hope that nobody else will invoke `toArray()`, because if they do, it will blow up.
2. Go to whoever gave you the assignment and protest that the guidelines of the assignment as given cannot receive a reasonable solution, because whoever designed that `Set` interface obviously never implemented it, or never attempted to invoke the `toArray()` method of their implementation.  If they did, they would have encountered the same error as you did.
3. Modify the constructor of your class implementing `Set` to accept the class of the elements, (so technically, you would not be altering the interface of `Set`,) so it would be invoked as follows:

`Set<ProfileInterface> following = new Set<>( ProfileInterface.class );`

then, use the following method to create an array from within `toArray()`:

```
public static <T> T newArray( Class<T> arrayType, int size )
{
    assert arrayType.isArray();
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    T array = (T)Array.newInstance( arrayType.getComponentType(), size );
    return array;
}
```

(you might want to play with it a bit to suit your needs, for example you might want to have it return `T[]` instead of `T`.)

***Unless, of course,*** the `Set` interface you are trying to implement is `java.util.Set`, in which case it does already have a `toArray( T[] )` method which you can override instead of `T[] toArray()`.

Comment: Thank you, you understand what I am getting at

Comment: @CupofJava please be sure to read the last sentence of my answer (the "Unless, of course" part.)

Comment: @CupofJava it's not super clear from the question that you're not, and that was the source of the confusion in my answer. You're talking about `Set` and `toArray()` - both well-known parts of the collections framework. I suppose you do say `Set<T> blah = new Set<T>()`; but it's worth stating explicitly that it's not `java.util.Set`.